# Django deploy to Production in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: django, apache2, virtualenv, python-3.5, mod-wsgi

I'm fairly new to django , i have to deploy the project to production mode in ubuntu 16.04. I have installed wsgi with apache2 and included the system path to the django project and python site-packages.

My sites-enabled/000-default.config is

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName myproject.com
        ServerAlias www.myproject.com

         Alias /static /var/www/html/TEST/myproject/static
         <Directory /var/www/html/TEST/myproject/static>
                Require all granted
         </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/TEST/myproject/myproject>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
                 </Files>
        </Directory>

      WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/var/www/html/TEST/newenv python-path=/var/www/html/TEST/myproject:/var/www/html/TEST/newenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup myproject
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/TEST/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

and my wsgi file

```
import os , sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/TEST/myproject/')

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/TEST/newenv/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

when i run the link i am getting  Internal Server Error(505)

and i have checked the error in the error log ,it's showing me  from

> django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application 
>   [wsgi:error] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Can someone please help me with this ? i have googled and checked out all other options and solutions . Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the Django package installed? Into the system Python, or the virtual environment? What do you get from command line ``python`` if you run ``import django; print(django.__file__)``? What version of Python is mod_wsgi compiled for? http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: You also should not name the Django project directory so it has a dot in the name. That is, don't use ``myproject.com``. That will cause problems with module imports when trying to import your Django settings file and project code.

Comment: The question would be less confusing if you used the real values. There is a mismatch between `myproject.com.settings` in your `wsgi` file and the location of the wsgi file `mysite/wsgi.py`. They should usually match because the settings and wsgi files are in the same directory by default. If the directory really is `mysite`, then `'mysite.settings'` will be ok. If it contains a dot (e.g. `myproject.com`) then that will cause problems as Graham says.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: @Alasdair , it is mysite , i have used dummy values instead of original name

Comment: @ramganesh , Yes i am

Comment: My point is, I can't tell whether the difference between `mysite/wsgi.py` and `myproject.com.settings` is because there's a problem in your config, or just because you've made a mistake when switching to dummy values. Is there really a dot in `myproject.com.settings` or did you just add it when switching to dummy values? You haven't answered Graham's questions from the first comment. Did you install mod wsgi with `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`?

Comment: Yeah , i have installed libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 . @Alasdair , and i will repost it with the coorrect configurations

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton , when i execute the print(django._file_) command  , i am getting the following path /var/www/html/TEST/newenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py  , which is the same as sys.append.path in wsgi.py file

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton , mod_wsgi version is 4.3.0 compiled for python3.5 and apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/var/www/html/TEST/newenv \
      python-path=/var/www/html/TEST/myproject:/var/www/html/TEST/newenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/TEST/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

all you should need is:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/var/www/html/TEST/newenv \
      python-path=/var/www/html/TEST/myproject
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/TEST/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

You don't need to add the `site-packages` directory.

In the `wsgi.py` file you don't need:

```
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/TEST/myproject/')
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/TEST/newenv/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/')
```

as `python-home` and `python-path` on `WSGIDaemonProcess` achieve same result.

Another issue is that you have put your Django project code under the directory `/var/www/html`. You should not put it there. That is the default `DocumentRoot` directory. If you were to uncomment `WSGIScriptAlias`, someone could download your source code. So is better to not put your code under that directory.

Now neither of those things should make a difference as far as solving your problem, as the first just gets of redundant settings. The second is just changing to better practices.

At this point, the only reason can see why Django module could not be found is if the permissions on the directories/files are such that the user that Apache runs your code as cannot read them. So check permissions on `/var/www/html/TEST/newenv`.

Comment: i have checked the ownership ,it has been given full ownership permissions . still i am getting the same

Comment: Add to your WSGI script file: ``print(os.listdir('/var/www/html/TEST/newenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages')``. Does that work and show you what is in that directory.

Comment: No , it does not . it's showing me the same error .

Comment: Where in the file did you put it? It needs to be before you do the import of ``django`` module and need to see what that produced in the log file.

Comment: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. i have inserted that print statement in wsgi.py before `from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application`

Comment: Fix the obvious error then of putting extra bracket at end. ``print(os.listdir('/var/www/html/TEST/newenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages'))``

Comment: i fixed that and restarted the apache2 . it showed me the same server not found error and i checked the log file , it shoed me the following error including no module named djano.core.wsgi .

Comment: ['setuptools-39.0.1.dist-info', 'configparser-3.5.0.dist-info', 'pytz', 'django', 'pkg_resources', 'mysqlclient-1.3.12.dist-info', 'configparser-3.5.0-py3.5-nspkg.pth', 'mod_wsgi-4.6.3.dist-info', 'backports', 'MySQLdb', 'wheel', 'pip-9.0.3.dist-info', 'easy_install.py', 'pip', 'pytz-2018.3.dist-info', 'wheel-0.30.0.dist-info', '_mysql_exceptions.py', 'setuptools', 'Django-2.0.3.dist-info', '__pycache__', 'mod_wsgi', '_mysql.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so']                                 Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/TEST/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

Comment: Change that to ``print(os.system('ls -lasR /var/www/html/TEST/newenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django')``. Also consider deleting the Python virtual environment and recreating it. Don't create it as root, make sure you are creating as a different user so you aren't inheriting restrictive permissions of root.